# Time data does not match specified format

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a string given in "DD MM YYYY" format into a datetime object. Here's the code for the same:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

s = "23 July 2001"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %m %Y")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '23 July 2001' does not match format '%d %m %Y'
```

What's wrong ? Isn't the format specified in the string the same as that specified by "%d %m %Y" ?

Comment: use `%B` instead of `%m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%m` means "Month as a zero-padded decimal number."

Your month is `July` so you should use `%B`, which is "Month as locale’s full name."

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Like behzad.nouri said, Use `d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %B %Y")`.
Or make `s = '23 07 2001' and d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %m %Y")`